# how to center a facebox ajax request properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, facebox

My wordpress template uses facebox to display portfolio images via ajax requests.

The problem is the images load in different positions depending on the viewers screen size.

My template uses

```
$('#facebox').css({
    top:    getPageScroll()[1] + (getPageHeight() / 10),
    left:   385.5
  }).show()
```

The facebox site uses

```
$('#facebox').css({
   top: getPageScroll()[1] + (getPageHeight() / 10),
   left: $(window).width() / 2 - 205
 }).show()
```

The facebox site displays images perfectly but when I use the same line with my template is doesn't display properly.

Can someone point me in the right direction for getting the images to load consistently in the center of the screen?

[Link to the portfolio site im trying to fix](http://karlie.ca)

[Link to the facebox site](http://defunkt.github.com/facebox/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Formula is: (window.width / 2) - (target.width / 2)

```
$('#facebox').css({
   top: getPageScroll()[1] + (getPageHeight() / 10),
   left: ($(window).width() / 2) - ($('#facebox').outerWidth() / 2)
 }).show()
```

Note, your facebox.css sets the div#facebox to 710px width, though your images are wider. I used outerWidth() instead of width(), but not sure if that accounts properly for the css 710px width.

Comment: thanks a lot. Could u tell me if I should set that div#facebox width to the width of the widest image in the set?

Comment: You could if you don't mind extra facebox space on either side. Perhaps it's an option to change the widths of the images to be uniform?

Comment: I don't understand the 710px width for facebox and 660px width for the facebox .body

I ask cuz unfortunately the template is no longer supported by its creator.

Comment: I will experiment. Thanks again. Its much better now.

Comment: actually, I think facebox resizes correctly, you just need it for the initial empty box. Aka. you don't need to change the with in the .css, so disregard that ;)